# Angular 17 - Unable to prevent unauthenticated user from accessing a protected route

Tags: angular, angular17

Below is my route code.  I'm trying to redirect unauthenticated users by default to the login page and authenticated users to the home route.   The home.guard checks if there is an authentication token in the localStorage.  However, even after logging out - I can go to any of the child routes.  I cannot see any data because the data API requires a token.  However, I can see all the HTML associated with the child pages. The logic should simply work as - if authenticated then go to home else go to login.   What am I doing wrong here?  I have spent almost 5 hours going through blog posts and you tube videos but cannot figure it out.  Do I need to put an authResolver?

```
import { CanActivate, CanActivateChild } from './guards/home.guard';

export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'login', title: 'Login', component:LoginComponent,
    },
    {
        path: 'signup', title: 'Sign Up', component:SignupComponent,
    },
    {
        path: '', component:SidebarComponent, canActivateChild: [CanActivateChild], 
        children:[
            {
                path: 'dashboard', title: 'Dashboard Blank', component:DashboardHomeComponent,
            },
            {
                path: 'profile', title: 'Profile', component:ProfileComponent,
            },
            {
                path: 'home', title: 'Dashboard Demo', component:DashboardComponent,
            }
        ]

   },
];
```

home.guard.ts code:

```
import { inject } from "@angular/core";
import { CanActivateFn, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { StorageService } from '../services/storage.service';

/** 
export const homeGuard: CanActivateFn = (route, state) => {
  return true;
};
*/

export const CanActivate = () => {

  const storageService = inject(StorageService);
  const router = inject (Router);
/** userData below is an array  with elements such as user_id, firstname, lastname, token etc. **/

  if (storageService.get('userData')) { 
     return true;
  } else {
    router.navigate(['login']);
    return false;
  }

}

export const CanActivateChild = () => {

  CanActivate();

}
```

Storage Service Code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StorageService {
  constructor() {}

  // Store the value
   async store(storageKey: string, value: any) {
   localStorage.setItem(storageKey, JSON.stringify(value));

  }
  
  // Get the value
  async get(storageKey: string) {
    let ret: any = localStorage.getItem( storageKey );
    return ret ? JSON.parse(<string>ret) : null;
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Can you share your canActivate code snippet ?

Comment: @DarshanUnadkat added code and additional context.

Comment: share your storageservice code did you try console.log when you were returning true?

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the value of `canActivate` function!

Please ensure when you logout the token is cleared from local storage

steps: Inspect Element (F12) -> application tab -> choose your url storage -> check if token is cleared!

```
export const CanActivate = () => {
  const storageService = inject(StorageService);
  const router = inject(Router);
/** userData below is an array  with elements such as user_id, firstname, lastname, token etc. **/
  if (storageService.get('userData')) { 
     return true;
  } else {
    router.navigate(['login']);
    return false;
  }
}

export const CanActivateChild = () => {
  return CanActivate(); // <- changed here!
}
```

In the storage service could you change like below!

```
  // Get the value
  async get(storageKey: string) {
    let ret: any = await localStorage.getItem( storageKey );
    return ret ? JSON.parse(<string>ret) : null;
  }
```

Comment: it didn't solve it.

Comment: Sorry but no luck.